# How do I get Panic Coda to use Github for Source Control?

Tags: git, version-control, github, coda

How do I get Panic Coda to use Github for Source Control?

Answer (score 4):

Get [Coda version 2](http://panic.com/coda/), recently released: it supports GIT.

Answer (score 1):

Coda only supports SVN  at the moment. That said, this might be helpful: http://getsatisfaction.com/panic/topics/are_you_using_coda_and_git [link to a now defunct community]

Answer (score 1):

github supports [svn read](https://github.com/blog/626-announcing-svn-support) and [write](https://github.com/blog/644-subversion-write-support) access.